# Why is `this` passed when the function doesn't need it?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86, calling-convention

```
class Ex2
{
private:
    int var1 = 9999;

public:
    virtual int sum(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    virtual void virtual_func1() {
        cout << "Ex2->virtual_func1" << endl;
    }

    virtual int funky(int a) {
        return (a * var1);
    }
};


class Ex3 : public Ex2
{
private:
    int var1 = 7777;

public:
    int subtract(int x, int y) {
        return x - y;
    }

    virtual void virtual_func1() {
        cout << "Ex3->virtual_func1" << endl;
    }

    int funky(int a) {
        return (a * var1 + 2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {

    Ex3* e = new Ex3();
    e->virtual_func1();
    e->funky(5)
    delete(e);
}
```

This is the example code, so what I expected was that the function is resolved via vtable, which it does quite fine and also passes this via `ecx` so the function can use `int var1` variable

I then modified the code to

```
class Ex2
{
private:
    int var1 = 9999;

public:
    virtual int sum(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    virtual void virtual_func1() {
        cout << "Ex2->virtual_func1" << endl;
    }

    virtual int funky(int a, int b) {
        return (a * b);
    }
};


class Ex3 : public Ex2
{
private:
    int var1 = 7777;

public:
    int subtract(int x, int y) {
        return x - y;
    }

    virtual void virtual_func1() {
        cout << "Ex3->virtual_func1" << endl;
    }

    int funky(int a, int b) {
        return (a * b + 2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {

    Ex3* e = new Ex3();
    e->virtual_func1();
    e->funky(8,4);
    delete(e);
}
```

This disassembles to:

```
push    esi
push    0Ch             ; Size
call    operator new(uint)
mov     esi, eax
add     esp, 4
mov     ecx, esi
mov     dword ptr [esi+4], 270Fh  ;constructor inlined?
mov     dword ptr [esi], offset const Ex3::`vftable' ;constructor inlined?
mov     dword ptr [esi+8], 1E61h ;constructor inlined?
call    sub_401010
mov     edx, [esi]
mov     ecx, esi                ;ecx as this
push    4                       ;push as para1
push    8                       ;push as para2
call    dword ptr [edx+8]       ;vtable call
push    0Ch
push    esi             ; Memory
call    sub_40140B
add     esp, 8
xor     eax, eax
pop     esi
retn
```

So I'm wondering why is he adding `this` when there is absolutely no need to have access to his own memory?

Furthermore what adds to this confusion is because

```
virtual void virtual_func1() {
    cout << "Ex2->virtual_func1" << endl;
}
```

should be a vtable call, yet somehow it's called directly

```
call    sub_401010
```

vtable

```
.rdata:004031C0 const Ex3::`vftable' dd offset sub_401000
.rdata:004031C0                                         ; DATA XREF: _main+16↑o
.rdata:004031C4                 dd offset sub_401010
.rdata:004031C8                 dd offset sub_401030
```

Why did it decide to bypass the vtable?

Comment: The caller can't know whether the function does or doesn't use `this`, especially when calling a virtual function.  Compilers tend not to invent custom calling conventions.  If you compiled with full optimization to let the compiler statically figure out the type in this simple case (and thus which function was being called), it could just inline it and not call at all.

Comment: *"Why did it decide to bypass the vtable?"* - That's an optimization called *devirtualization*.